# Prerequisites for the Gauss-Green theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, self-learning

Consider the following theorem from Appendix C from Evans' PDE book:

[image]
[image]

I know about integration in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but not about how to make sense of the integrals on the right-hand side. As my time is *very* limited, I can't read 50+ pages on the general theory of integration on manifolds. **I am in desperate need of a text that in a minimum amount of space manages to get myself acquainted with those integrals and the proof of (i) from above.**
It's a plus if the text has some worked examples (the proofs from those statements of the text, that are intuitively plausible, I want to skip anyway because I don't have sufficient time).

**Note: This question is a total re-edit. For further details please consult the edit history.**

Comment: I would be surprised if such a reference existed. The best setting for [Stokes's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) is indeed differential geometry (not "manifold theory"). Anyway: "surface integral" just means "sum up stuff defined on a surface" just like a usual real integral is "sum up stuff defined on a line". The intuition of $dS(y)$ is "the infinitesimal surface element at $y$", but if you are unwilling to learn about differential forms, then you should just take it as a useful formal shorthand.

Comment: Also, please note that to "obtain a working knowledge" of a new field of mathematics you (like anyone else) *have* to familiarize yourself with the proof techniques specific to that field, and this entails reading through some proofs. You may skip them to get an idea of where the book is going, but you should definitely read most of them.

Comment: @A.P. Well, isn't there maybe a book like Wade's but where the setting directly is $n$ dimensional, instead of $3$-dimensional, because he in those low dimensions doesn't use differential form. So what I'm saying is, isn't there a text that develops the theory without formally introducing differential forms (because that saves time, as one doesn't have to develop "calculus" for them), but instead develops everything how in would specialize to the case for surfaces in $n$ dimensional euclidean space ?

Comment: Not even a new comment ? C'mon people...

Comment: There is a legend that Henri Cartan used to bother Andre' Weil about Stokes' Theorem and the fact that no proof of it exists. Years past, they wrote a bunch of books together, proved a lot, but never Stokes' theorem.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki That's depressing

Comment: @pink_pyjamas Do not let that worry you. If every time you come across a result that bother you, because you have to accept it, without proof, then you will never be able to finish a subject! My recommendation is to prove the theorem on a $n$-sphere. In "practical" applications to the theory of PDE's this is essentially all you need. One can get a lot of results about harmonic functions by integrating over spheres only.

Comment: Could you please provide me with a reference for a proof on $n$-sphere ? That already would helpt me out a lot!

Comment: @pink_pyjamas I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but "Harmonic Function Theory" does talk about integration on sphere. Maybe this be helpful? http://www.axler.net/HFT.pdf

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki I looked through it - just like Evans it also has an appendix where integrals with respect to "surface measure" come up, but it too doesn't have a proof or an explanation how this intergral is defined.

Comment: @pink_pyjamas You can always send Evans an e-mail, and ask the man himself!

Comment: The  minimum prerequisite for Evan's text is, to my knowledge, an intermediate level undergraduate real analysis course discussing the theory of real functions on metric spaces corresponding to the first 8 chapters of "baby Rudin, and in addition, some linear algebra and differential equations..Most students at Berkeley who take Evans' course have at least a semester of graduate analysis including the basics of measure theory and integration. For most of the book,though, I don't think you need this much background.

Comment: There is a really simple caption about Stokes theorem in the book Differential Forms in Algebraic topology by Bott and Tu. It needs almost nothing. (F. Riesz or B. Szőkefalvi-Nagy said once that the proofs of very general theorems are ordinary very simple)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're really asking for a textbook giving a modern and careful presentation of vector calculus/calculus of functions of several variables.Since you're reading Evan's text,I'll assume you've had a least a good undergraduate course in real analysis of one variable on metric spaces a la "baby Rudin" or Pugh. I'll also assume you've got a decent background in linear algebra, which is really important in understanding a careful proof of the variants of Stokes' Theorem, which is really what the Guass-Green theorem is a special case of.

The standard books for learning this material are *Calculus On Manifolds* by the legendary Micheal Spivak and *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres. Spivak's book is basically a problem course with quite a few pictures. It's quite rough going,but it's worth the effort if you've got the patience. Munkres is more of a standard textbook and covers the same material with much more detail.Since you're looking for a rapid introduction that'll cover the material in minimum space, Spivak really will fill your needs best **if** you're willing to work through it.Indeed, the entire point of the book is to build to careful proofs of the variants of Stokes' theorem. Munkres sacrifices brevity for clarity, so if you need more detail, that's a better choice.Be warned,though-Munkres has a bit more in the way of prerequisites then Spivak. Spivak basically assumes only good courses in linear algebra  and rigorous $\epsilon-\delta$ single variable calculus while Munkres assumes in addition, a good working knowledge of basic topology in metric spaces.Both books work mostly in $R^n$ and discuss abstract manifolds at the end in passing. Both are still really good choices-again, it depends on how much time you have to invest.

A third book you might want to check out for an excellent rigorous discussion  of Green and Stokes' theorems is Loring Tu's *An Introduction To Manifolds*. The purpose of Tu's book is to give a clear and relatively short introduction to the theory of differential forms and manifolds **with only a background in undergraduate algebra and real analysis.** Specifically, the purpose of the book is to provide all the essential background in manifolds that's needed to read the classic text on algebraic topology he co-wrote with Raoul Bott, *Differential Forms In Algebraic Topology*. That being said, the book contains all the basics with many pictures and is extremely readable. Chapters 21-24 contain an in-depth presentation of statements and proofs of both the Green-Gauss theorem and the general Stokes' Theorem, which the GG theorem is a special case of. I think this book will also serve your needs very well.

I think any of these books will be good choices for you. But again,if brevity is paramount here and you're willing to work through it with a pen and paper, Spivak is probably your best choice.

Good luck!

Comment: But doe the theorems for $R^2$ and $R^3$ generalize so easily to $R^n$ because to read Evans in need to be able to find my way around $R^n$ (resp. to understand the above Green-Gauss, which is formulated in $R^n$)

Comment: -1.  This does not answer the question, which asks specifically for something that works in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Also, all the rambling verbiage is entirely unnecessary and makes this answer far harder to read than it needs to be.  Brevity = soul of wit.

Comment: @AdamSmith  Firstly, "brevity is the soul of wit"-In your opinion. It seems like a petty excuse to downvote me,which you love to do.  Secondly-you cannot generalize this theorem to $R^n$ without the machinery of n-forms. It's simply not possible. Now I chose to give the OP a relatively simple text since I wasn't sure what his or her background was. In retrospect, probably a mistake. I'll add an appropriate reference when I have a minute.

Comment: I downvoted you because you didn't even attempt to answer the question.   There are a million books that do this stuff in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$; I don't see why your personal favorite is at all relevant here.  The comments on your style are intended for your benefit, though I am aware that trying to make you write well is a losing game.

Comment: Sigh. I give up.I edited the answer considerably.

Comment: "this is the book we all wish our teachers had handed us" [citation-needed].  Given that I'm included in "all", I'd request that you refrain from putting words in my mouth.

Comment: @Adam SmithI deleted the repost and replaced the original with the new version. Do what you will to it,it's for the OP's benefit. I hope it helps him or her find what he/she needs,not our egos. I thought that's what this site was for.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 The fact that you didn't answer the question makes egos irrelevant... and this is the first time I've downvoted you so it's not a vendetta, sorry.

Comment: the presently -3 downvotes for this answer are pretty crazy, because it *does* address the question of whether there's a fast introduction to said integral, to which the answer, to the best knowledge of the answerer seems to be negative, and it also gives me a couple of book references. therefore this answer definitely has relevant content,for which it gets its well-deserved +1 from me. I also have to remark that some of the remarks of Adam Smith or John Colanduoni, while their content is a valid opinion (I welcome them to provide better answers if they feel the present one is that bad), [...]

Comment: [...] they are phrased in a somewhat offensive manner, which is unnecessary and I can well imagine that Mathemagician1234, after having put in a lot of work (+ the reedit), doesn't fell good about reading that. Before awarding the bounty I'm still going to wait a few days, because maybe there *is* a miraculuous book that fits even better (I have yet to look through your books, I could be that they are the best that's possible in my case, but one never knows).

Comment: I hope you don't feel offended, that I didn't award you the bounty, as you definitely put more work into an answer. Unfortunately the bounty   can't be split, because although digiboys notes are suited to my (special) needs a bit better,  you're references were also valuable, but may come into fruition only when I have more time. Because of this, let me at least show recognition by accepting your answer, which also provides  you with some rep points. I hope this way I managed to balance the rep points a bit between these two answers, as both were helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this not-too-long notes will help
http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/chap14.pdf

It gives some rather elementary explanations and proof of the Gauss theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For the complete set of notes (used for an honors calculus class at Rice University) covering other related topics, refer to http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/

Comment: +1. A very nice set of notes,indeed! One of my favorites on my website that will finally go live this week.But I think my recommendations are better,sorry......................

Comment: Really? A +25 bounty for a set of lecture notes? It's a good set of notes,no question-but really?